# PyPDF2 Extract from field or location

Tags: python, pypdf

I have a python script running fine, it scans a folder and collects data based on text line position which could work great but if any lines have missing data it throws my numbers off obviously.
I have looked in the pdf file using iText RUPS and I can find a reference to one set of the data I need

```
BT
582 -158.78 Td
(213447) Tj
ET
```

the information I want is in the brackets, can I somehow use the coordinates? if all fails, I might be able to get people to agree to start the info I need to collect with a flag XX12345 or YY12345 then I can easily pick out the data from the text extraction, but I'd rather find a better way.

Not added code examples as that works fine it's just the next step I'm struggling with, but I can if anyone wishes.

Many thanks

I tried to use just text extraction, but missing inputs throw my numbering scheme off.

Comment: what means `lines have missing data`? what is `correct data` in opposite? Is `(213447) Tj` should be `213447`? You can use regex or simply `''.join([x for x in line if x in ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']])` if you need to extract only numbers

Comment: @rzlvmp If the user does not complete a field within the form then when I output by lines the location of my data changes, I cannot search for the data because its different every time so I need to capture the input of a field which don't output in such a way.

Comment: Using pymupdf combined with pypdf2 I seem to have a working solution. I will add code when I'm at the PC next